# How many TNT will kill you with Blast Protection armour?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How many TNT does it take for you to die, with Blast Protection armour? 
When telling me how many hits it will take, please be specific to what you are saying.

How many hits of TNT for each armour.

- Leather
- Gold
- Chain
- Iron
- Diamond

Comment: I may test it a little bit and type the results as the answer

Answer (score 1):

All of the following testing is done with a direct blast of TNT and full sets of Blast Protection IV armor:

- Leather - 2 hits
- Gold - 2 hits
- Chain - 3 hits
- Iron - 3 hits
- Diamond - 5 hits